# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value) django mysql

Tags: mysql, django, apache, ubuntu

hi i created a django project and tried to deploy it on ubuntu apache server with mysql database

but when i run `python3 manage.py migrate` i get this error :

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x88\xDB\x95\xD8\xB3...' for column 'name' at row 1")

i have only one column named `name = models.CharField(max_length=30)`

when i run `show variables like 'char%';` the output is :

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

and in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` i set `[client] default-character-set = utf8`
is there something i've missed ?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The “utf8” encoding only supports three bytes per character so, you cannot store 4-byte characters in MySQL with the utf-8 character set.

For more info read [this](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434)

1.Change your MySQL database, table and columns to use the utf8mb4 character set

2.In your **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have to change that to utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

I changed "mysql" to "mariadb" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
```

if you remove this while migrating cities_light it should work, make sure to add it again after migration